# cssselector is not supported. Getting error in Appium

Tags: jquery, css, xpath, intellij-idea, appium

How can i click on `Supermarkt`?

```
<div class="answerButton">
  <div class="answerButtonBg" style="background: rgb(255, 165, 31);">
    <div class="text">Supermarkt</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried

```
WebDriverWait  driverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver , 20);
driverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("#answerButtonBg div.text"))).getText();
driverWait.click();'
```

The error i am getting is

> Locator Strategy 'css selector' is not supported for this session.

Can anyone answer and is there a better way to click on `Supermarkt`

Comment: This is the html from where i am trying to extact the text.
<div class="answerButton ">

<div class="answerButtonBg" style="background: rgb(255, 165, 31);">

<div class="text">Supermarkt</div></div></div>

Comment: Please take care to format your questions so they are human-readable.

Comment: For accessing the CSS selector, first switch from native to webview then try your code. This link helps you https://discuss.appium.io/t/switch-to-webview-using-getcontexthandles/578/15